# Printing list inside queryset loop in a Table

Tags: python, django, html-table

I'm parsing HTML using lxml and trying to print the list items in a table using Django templates.

So far I've been able to print everything except the items of a list. When I use a for loop to print the items, it treats the list as string and prints each character.

Here is the Django template code. anchortext is the list whose items I want to display but using the current code it is displaying each character including every bracket, comma and colons.

```
{% for item in query_results %}
<tbody>
    <tr>

    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    .
    .
    .        
    {% for items in item.anchortext %}
    <td colspan="2">
    {{ items }}
    </td>
            {% endfor %}
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
query_results=Document.objects.order_by('-id')     
        context ={
            "query_results": query_results,
        }
        return render(request, "result.html", context)
```

EDIT1: This is anchortext; ['longboard brands', 'best penny board']

If I print it using

```
    {% for items in anchor %}
        {%  for x in items %}
            {{ x }}
            {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the output as this
['beginner longboarder', 'riding style']

If I use

```
{% for items in anchor %}
        {{ items }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the o/p as 
(u"['beginner longboarder', 'riding style']",)

EDIT2: I am getting anchortext using this

```
Mymodels=Document()
Mymodels.anchortext = tree.xpath('//article[1]//p//a[contains(@href,'+'"'+domain+'"'+' )]/text()')
```

I am getting domain from user.

Any help?

Comment: Where are the `item.anchortext` values coming from? What is the column type? Thanks.

Comment: item.anchortext is a list of strings. I am parsing HTML using lxml so it has some string data in the form of ['beginner longboarder', 'riding style']. I want to display beginner longboarder and riding style seperately.

Comment: anchortext appears to be a single string, not a list of strings. It may contain commas and quotes, but that doesn't make it a list. How are you storing it?

Comment: This is anchortext; ['longboard brands', 'best penny board']

Comment: Sigh, you already said that. How are you creating that? How are you storing it?

Comment: Sorry. Please check Edits 1 and 2.

Comment: So, as I said, it is a string, not a list.

Comment: I just tried to split the string in the django shell and got this error
mlist = anchortext.split(",")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'